Getting Error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x2f30650004) in swift
I am very new to swift, please help me.
I am trying to make https request in swift, with identity created from certificate and key. My code look like this
To create the identity.
func loadIdentity(certificate: String, privateKey: String)-> SecIdentity? { guard let certData = Data(base64Encoded: certificate, options:NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) else { print("Unable to decode certificate PEM") return nil }
 guard let cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(kCFAllocatorDefault, certData as CFData) else {
        return nil
    }
let addCertQuery: [String: Any] = [kSecClass as String: kSecClassCertificate,
                                   kSecValueRef as String: cert,
                                   kSecAttrLabel as String: "certificateLabel"]


let tag = "fedvfdvdf-tag".data(using: .utf8)!
_ = deleteCertificateAndKey(certLabel: "certificateLabel",keyTag: tag )
let certAddStatus = SecItemAdd(addCertQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
guard let pemKeyData = Data(base64Encoded: privateKey, options:NSData.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) else {
     return nil
   }
let sizeInBits = pemKeyData.count * 8
let keyDict: [CFString: Any] = [
  kSecAttrKeyType: kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
  kSecAttrKeyClass: kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate,
  kSecAttrKeySizeInBits: NSNumber(value: sizeInBits),
  kSecReturnPersistentRef: true
]

var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
   guard let key = SecKeyCreateWithData(pemKeyData as CFData, keyDict as CFDictionary, &error) else {
     return nil
   }
let addKeyQuery: [String: Any] = [
     kSecClass as String: kSecClassKey,
     kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: true,
     kSecValueRef as String: key,
     kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: tag
   ]
 
   let privKeyAddStatus = SecItemAdd(addKeyQuery as CFDictionary, nil)
let getIdentityQuery = [
    kSecClass : kSecClassIdentity,
    kSecReturnData : true,
    kSecReturnAttributes : true,
    kSecReturnRef : true,
    kSecMatchLimit : kSecMatchLimitAll
    ] as CFDictionary
var identityItem: CFTypeRef?
let status = SecItemCopyMatching(getIdentityQuery , &identityItem)
print("identityItem finished with status: \(String(describing: identityItem))")
print("status finished with status: \(status)")
guard status == errSecSuccess else {
       print("Unable to create identity")
       return nil
   }
return (identityItem as! SecIdentity);
}

to make api request. Code is breaking in this function, around this lines
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in and let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: URLSessionPinningDelegate(identity: identity), delegateQueue: nil)
For testing I removed identity and just used default URLSession, and request start giving response (although it was 401 but it was not crashing), so my guess is error is because of URLSession.
func makeAzureRequest(scopeId:String, registrationId:String, key:String, certificate:String, provisionHost:String, fileNameWithFolder:String, modelId:String, completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void ) throws { guard let identity = loadIdentity(certificate: certificate, privateKey: key) else { throw NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unable to create identity"])
}

 let session = URLSession(configuration: .default, delegate: URLSessionPinningDelegate(identity: identity), delegateQueue: nil)
print("session: \(session)")
 guard let url = URL(string: "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net/\(scopeId)/registrations/\(registrationId)/register?api-version=2021-06-01") else {
     throw NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Invalid URL"])
   
 }
   var request = URLRequest(url: url)

 request.httpMethod = "PUT"
 request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
 request.setValue("utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Encoding")

 let body = ["registrationId": registrationId]
 request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: [])
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
     if let error = error {
         completion(.failure(error))
     } else if let data = data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
         completion(.success(responseString))
     }else {
         completion(.failure(NSError(domain: "", code: -1, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "Unknown error occurred"])))
     }
 }

 task.resume()
}

to call function where api function is triggered.
@objc(AzureProvisionWithCertificate)
class AzureProvisionWithCertificate: NSObject {

  @objc(provisionAndUploadFile:withRegistrationId:withKey:withCertificate:withProvisionHost:withFileNameWithFolder:withModelId:withResolver:withRejecter:)
  func provisionAndUploadFile(scopeId:String, registrationId:String, key:String, certificate:String,  provisionHost:String,  fileNameWithFolder:String,  modelId:String, resolve:@escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock, reject:@escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
      print("starting swift code here")
      do {
              try makeAzureRequest(scopeId: scopeId, registrationId:registrationId, key: key, certificate: certificate, provisionHost: provisionHost, fileNameWithFolder: fileNameWithFolder, modelId: modelId) { result in
                  switch result {
                  case .success(let responseString):
                      print("Success! Response: \(responseString)")
                      // Handle success, perhaps update the UI or process the response
                  case .failure(let error):
                      print("Failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                      // Handle failure, perhaps show an error message to the user
                  }
              }
          } catch {
              print("Failed to initiate request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
//              throw error
          }
      
  }
  
}

And URLSessionPinningDelegate class look like this to SSL pinning.
import Foundation 
import Security

class URLSessionPinningDelegate: NSObject, URLSessionDelegate { var identity: SecIdentity

init(identity: SecIdentity) {
    self.identity = identity
}

 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                 didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                 completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
   if challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod == NSURLAuthenticationMethodClientCertificate {
     let credential = URLCredential(identity: self.identity,
                                    certificates: nil,
                                    persistence: .forSession)
     completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)
   } else {
     completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
   }
 }
}

Stack trace for crash:

  * frame #0: 0x000000019e78b038 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend + 56

    frame #1: 0x00000001af0be964 Security`SecIdentityCopyCertificate + 24

    frame #2: 0x00000001d7e3fd2c libboringssl.dylib`boringssl_identity_create_from_identity + 92

    frame #3: 0x00000001d7e50488 libboringssl.dylib`boringssl_context_set_identity + 284

    frame #4: 0x00000001d7e500dc libboringssl.dylib`__boringssl_context_certificate_request_callback_block_invoke_3 + 1048

    frame #5: 0x00000001a6de6230 Network`nw_queue_context_async_if_needed + 88

    frame #6: 0x00000001d7e4fc9c libboringssl.dylib`__boringssl_context_certificate_request_callback_block_invoke_2 + 148

    frame #7: 0x00000001a7b43668 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol8855 + 576

    frame #8: 0x00000001a7bdab08 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol12666 + 204

    frame #9: 0x00000001a7b43b08 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol8863 + 700

    frame #10: 0x00000001a7b86738 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol10375 + 84

    frame #11: 0x00000001a7b869d0 CFNetwork`___lldb_unnamed_symbol10379 + 36

    frame #12: 0x00000001079e0b98 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32

    frame #13: 0x00000001079e27bc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_client_callout + 20

    frame #14: 0x00000001079ea66c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 832

    frame #15: 0x00000001079eb43c libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_lane_invoke + 460

    frame #16: 0x00000001079ecabc libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_invoke + 2336

    frame #17: 0x00000001079f8404 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 328

    frame #18: 0x00000001079f7a38 libdispatch.dylib`_dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 444

    frame #19: 0x0000000203763934 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_wqthread + 288

Thanks in Advance!!!

Do you have the ability to externally create a .p12 or .pfx file and import that instead? That would be a much easier solution for you. You can find more about that over here

openssl pkcs12 -export -out test.p12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.pem -name "Test" should be the command to combine the two

If I use my certificate and privatekey .pem file and create .p12 using this https://gist.github.com/jdanthinne/8a6557744ba5498de1952d176d293293 , will it be helpful?

That looks promising, you certainly could try that. I do believe though that some of those functions are macOS only, but not sure
